# Windows 10 Styled ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, contextmenu, windows-10

Is there a way to create ContextMenuStrip using Visual Studio and Forms with Windows 10 style. I know, that its Renderer can be changed in order to have look like Windows Vista, 7 and 8. And that is what I made:

[image]

But I also would like to make it look like this in Windows 10:

[image]

Is there a way to do it using Windows Forms, or it should be done in some special way, using Metro classes etc?

Comment: If you want it exactly the same then you need to use the native menu component wrapper instead.  Right-click the toolbox > Choose Items > .NET Framework components tab > tick "ContextMenu".

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I would like to use ContextMenuStrip exactly, because it has some features, I wanted to implement in my application. I am sure, it is still possible to change Renderer of ContextMenuStrip, in order to change its visual style.

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing, but with the native Win32 HMENU instead of a WinForms ContextMenu (doing this for a lightweight C++ app sitting in the system tray). Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement your custom [`Renderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and override `OnRenderArrow` and `OnRenderItemCheck` and pass your custom [`ColorTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to it. Then set it as `Renderer` of your `ContextMenu`.

[image]

**Code for ColorTable:**

```
public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return Color.WhiteSmoke; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.WhiteSmoke; }
    }
    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
    {
        get { return Color.White; }
    }
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.White; }
    }
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.White; }
    }
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.White; }
    }
}
```

**Code for Renderer:**

```
public class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer()
        : base(new MyColorTable())
    {
    }
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var r = new Rectangle(e.ArrowRectangle.Location, e.ArrowRectangle.Size);
        r.Inflate(-2, -6);
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, new Point[]{
        new Point(r.Left, r.Top),
        new Point(r.Right, r.Top + r.Height /2), 
        new Point(r.Left, r.Top+ r.Height)});
    }

    protected override void OnRenderItemCheck(ToolStripItemImageRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var r = new Rectangle(e.ImageRectangle.Location, e.ImageRectangle.Size);
        r.Inflate(-4, -6);
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, new Point[]{
        new Point(r.Left, r.Bottom - r.Height /2),
        new Point(r.Left + r.Width /3,  r.Bottom), 
        new Point(r.Right, r.Top)});
    }
}
```

**Code for Form Load:**

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Worked just perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer the two ready-to-use context menu renderers

**VS 2019 Light:**

[image: VS 2019 Light context menu strip renderer]

```
#Region "References"
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
#End Region

Namespace MenuStripRenderer

    Public Class VS2019LightBlueRenderer

        Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

#Region "Colors"

        ReadOnly _colorMenuArrow As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
        ReadOnly _colorCheckSquare As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
        ReadOnly _colorCheckMark As Color = Color.FromArgb(19, 69, 99)
        ReadOnly _colorMenuItemText As Color = Color.FromArgb(33, 33, 33)

#End Region

#Region "Constructor"

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(New MenuStripColorTable())
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Overridden Methods"

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderArrow(e As ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs)

            'Draw arrow color
            If e IsNot Nothing Then e.ArrowColor = _colorMenuArrow
            MyBase.OnRenderArrow(e)

        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemText(e As ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs)

            If e IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim textRect = e.TextRectangle
                textRect.Height = e.Item.Height - 4 '4 is the default difference between the item height and the text rectangle height

                e.TextRectangle = textRect
                e.TextFormat = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
                e.TextColor = _colorMenuItemText

            End If

            MyBase.OnRenderItemText(e)

        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e As ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)

            If e Is Nothing OrElse Not e.Item.Enabled Then Return
            MyBase.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e)

        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemCheck(e As ToolStripItemImageRenderEventArgs)

            If e IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim g = e.Graphics
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

                Dim rectImage = New Rectangle(e.ImageRectangle.Location, e.ImageRectangle.Size)
                rectImage.Inflate(-1, -1)

                Using p = New Pen(_colorCheckSquare, 1)
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, rectImage)
                End Using

                Dim rectCheck = rectImage
                rectCheck.Width = rectImage.Width - 6
                rectCheck.Height = rectImage.Height - 8
                rectCheck.X += 3
                rectCheck.Y += 4

                Using p = New Pen(_colorCheckMark, 2)
                    g.DrawLines(p, {New Point(rectCheck.Left, rectCheck.Bottom - CInt(rectCheck.Height / 2)), New Point(rectCheck.Left + CInt(rectCheck.Width / 3), rectCheck.Bottom), New Point(rectCheck.Right, rectCheck.Top)})
                End Using

            End If

        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Classes"

        Private Class MenuStripColorTable

            Inherits ProfessionalColorTable

#Region "Colors"

            ReadOnly _colorMenuBorder As Color = Color.FromArgb(204, 206, 219)
            ReadOnly _colorMenuItemSelected As Color = Color.FromArgb(201, 222, 245)
            ReadOnly _colorBackground As Color = Color.FromArgb(246, 246, 246)
            ReadOnly _colorSeparator As Color = Color.FromArgb(224, 227, 230)
            ReadOnly _colorStatusStripGradient As Color = Color.FromArgb(234, 237, 241)
            ReadOnly _colorButtonSelected As Color = Color.FromArgb(88, 146, 226)
            ReadOnly _colorButtonPressed As Color = Color.FromArgb(110, 160, 230)

#End Region

#Region "Properties"

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ToolStripDropDownBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuStripGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuStripGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CheckBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CheckPressedBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CheckSelectedBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelected As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorMenuItemSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientMiddle As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorMenuItemSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorMenuBorder
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SeparatorDark As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorSeparator
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SeparatorLight As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorSeparator
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property StatusStripGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorStatusStripGradient
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property StatusStripGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorStatusStripGradient
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedGradientMiddle As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedGradientMiddle As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

#End Region

        End Class

#End Region

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**VS 2019 Dark:**

[image: VS 2019 Dark context menu strip renderer]

```
#Region "References"
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
#End Region

Namespace MenuStripRenderer

    Public Class VS2019DarkBlueRenderer

        Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

#Region "Colors"

        ReadOnly _colorMenuArrow As Color = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237)
        ReadOnly _colorCheckSquare As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
        ReadOnly _colorCheckMark As Color = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237)
        ReadOnly _colorMenuItemText As Color = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237)

#End Region

#Region "Constructor"

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(New MenuStripColorTable())
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Overridden Methods"

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderArrow(e As ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs)

            If e IsNot Nothing Then e.ArrowColor = _colorMenuArrow
            MyBase.OnRenderArrow(e)

        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemCheck(e As ToolStripItemImageRenderEventArgs)

            If e IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim g = e.Graphics
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

                Dim rectImage = New Rectangle(e.ImageRectangle.Location, e.ImageRectangle.Size)
                rectImage.Inflate(-1, -1)

                Using p = New Pen(_colorCheckSquare, 1)
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, rectImage)
                End Using

                Dim rectCheck = rectImage
                rectCheck.Width = rectImage.Width - 6
                rectCheck.Height = rectImage.Height - 8
                rectCheck.X += 3
                rectCheck.Y += 4

                Using p = New Pen(_colorCheckMark, 2)
                    g.DrawLines(p, {New Point(rectCheck.Left, rectCheck.Bottom - CInt(rectCheck.Height / 2)), New Point(rectCheck.Left + CInt(rectCheck.Width / 3), rectCheck.Bottom), New Point(rectCheck.Right, rectCheck.Top)})
                End Using

            End If

        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemText(e As ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs)

            If e IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim textRect = e.TextRectangle
                textRect.Height = e.Item.Height - 4 '4 is the default difference between the item height and the text rectangle height

                e.TextRectangle = textRect
                e.TextFormat = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
                e.TextColor = _colorMenuItemText

            End If

            MyBase.OnRenderItemText(e)

        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e As ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)

            If e Is Nothing OrElse Not e.Item.Enabled Then Return
            MyBase.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e)

        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Classes"

        Private Class MenuStripColorTable

            Inherits ProfessionalColorTable

#Region "Colors"

            ReadOnly _colorMenuBorder As Color = Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 67)
            ReadOnly _colorMenuItemSelected As Color = Color.FromArgb(76, 76, 77)
            ReadOnly _colorBackground As Color = Color.FromArgb(43, 43, 43)
            ReadOnly _colorSeparator As Color = Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 67)
            ReadOnly _colorStatusStripGradient As Color = Color.FromArgb(234, 237, 241)
            ReadOnly _colorButtonSelected As Color = Color.FromArgb(88, 146, 226)
            ReadOnly _colorButtonPressed As Color = Color.FromArgb(110, 160, 230)

#End Region

#Region "Properties"

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ToolStripDropDownBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuStripGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuStripGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CheckBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CheckPressedBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CheckSelectedBackground As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemSelected As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorMenuItemSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientMiddle As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ImageMarginGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorBackground
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuItemBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorMenuItemSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MenuBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorMenuBorder
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SeparatorDark As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorSeparator
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SeparatorLight As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorSeparator
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property StatusStripGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorStatusStripGradient
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property StatusStripGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorStatusStripGradient
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedGradientMiddle As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonSelectedBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonSelected
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedGradientBegin As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedGradientMiddle As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedGradientEnd As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ButtonPressedBorder As Color
                Get
                    Return _colorButtonPressed
                End Get
            End Property

#End Region

        End Class

#End Region

    End Class

End Namespace
```