# Windows 10-styled context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, windows-10

I noticed on Windows 10, it has a new styled context menu like this...

[image]

but on most other apps it has this style

[image]

And also it has a feature that on touch devices when you right click, the menu gets bigger.

Is there a way of implementing this in my app?

Comment: You may find my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32788174/3110834) helpful. Let me know :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Styled ContextMenuStrip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786250/windows-10-styled-contextmenustrip)

Comment: But how could I do this with just a ContextMenu?

Comment: @DylanBriedis If you follow the steps of that answer, you simply can apply it to `ContextMenuStrip`