# Customizing appearance of Form and Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have set the BackColor property of the form and all controls within it to white, but still some of it has the Control (gray) color (e.g. the context menu of the MenuStrip, the tabs of the TabControl, and the border of the form itself).

[image]

Basically I'm trying to make the appearance of my application in flat white.
Is it possible to achieve this in WinForms?

Comment: For `TabControl`, you should make it owner-draw and paint it yourself, for `MenuStrip` you can change items color individually or create a new `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` which draws the strip using the custom theme.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  can you please post a link where I can find a sample code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260827/17034

Comment: Or [Windows 10 Styled ContextMenuStrip](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32788174/3110834)

Comment: how about for the tabs? do you have any sample links?

Comment: There are many examples available on the net, for example [A .NET Flat TabControl (CustomDraw)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12185/A-NET-Flat-TabControl-CustomDraw)