# I want create windows 10 style menu for notifyicon in Tray app

Tags: .net, winforms, uwp, system-tray, trayicon

I am developing UWP app (open to choose any other kind of app) which will run in system tray. I want to customize context menu from conventional to windows 10 style.

UWP currently does not provide `NotifyIcon` (System tray icon). But [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP%20Systray) project helped me to create a bridge which helps to add winforms `NotifyIcon` control to UWP app. But I want this `NotifyIcon` context menu to look elegant.

first pic on shows default context menu .net provides and the second pic is the kind of context menu which I need.

[image: conventional]

[image: desired]

can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You can create a custom renderer like this: [Windows 10 Styled ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32786250/3110834). Just change the colors of the color table to what you need.

Comment: A UWP app cannot directly support a NotifyIcon, it gets suspended by the OS when it loses the foreground.  So cannot respond to menu selections.  The GitHub project in fact uses a secondary process, one that is not a UWP native app at all.  And can thus support NotifyIcon.  But is limited to using non-UWP controls throughout, you cannot use the MenuFlyout class.  You can only make it look like one.  Making it look different from the context menus provided by all the other tray icons, meh, maybe not such a good idea.

Comment: It seems like Microsoft hasn't even figured this out yet.  I right click on my the network tray icon and I get a dark W10 theme context menu, but I right click on the battery, the audio, Windows Defender, or OneDrive and it's a white old style context menu. And I'm running 1709. So it might not be worth worrying about yet.

Comment: any update on this question?
I actually want to go to the next level and create something like Microsoft People app with a modern UI popup that reside in the taskbar