# Change colour of MenuStrip checkbox tick?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I've created a custom renderer to change the style of the MenuStrip using `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` with `ProfessionalColorTable` where colours are defined like so:

```
public override Color MenuBorder => Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50);;
```

There are overrides for checkbox background & border colour:

```
public override Color CheckBackground => //Checkbox Checked BG
public override Color ButtonSelectedBorder => //Checkbox Checked Border
public override Color CheckSelectedBackground => //Highlighted Checkbox Checked BG
public override Color CheckPressedBackground => //Pressed Checkbox Checked BG
```

But there doesn't seem to be any way to change the forecolor? (The colour of the tick)

I'm able to make a custom CheckBox control inheriting the default CheckBox where I can change the back/forecolor by overriding the `OnPaint` method.

But I don't know whether there's a way to get the MenuStrip to use my custom checkbox? Is it possible if I make a custom MenuStrip control?

Comment: You can override [`OnRenderItemCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.onrenderitemcheck?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`. For example [Windows 10 Styled ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788174/3110834)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Is there similar overrides for styling the textbox & dropdown box in context menu?