# Create Context Menu like Desktop context menu C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a context menu like Desktop context menu
But I don't have any idea, can anybody tell me how to do the same as possible

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a custom renderer [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788174/3110834).

Comment: Change `BackColor`, Add some Icons